# How to alert if an unwanted Cookie was set on my own website?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, javascript, cookies

My website needs 4 different cookies. From time to time an additional cookie appears (Update: for my domain!) that is not set through my PHP code. As I do not use external javascripts as long I'm logged in as admin I really like to know what set this cookie.

My primary browser is Google Chrome so I like to know if there is an extension available that alerts me if a new cookie is set and which url/script did that. My first idea was a proxy that filters all HTTP responses, but as Javascript is able to set cookies as well it must be something that monitors that, too. Any ideas? Update: Only those that are set for my domain.

Comment: What are you using to make the website? The webhost or some such might be setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are cookie manager extensions for Chrome that can alert you. REF "Vanilla Cookie Manager" at [How to Block All Cookies Except for Sites You Use](http://www.howtogeek.com/63721/how-to-block-all-cookies-except-for-sites-you-use/)

However I don't think it can detect the source page or script that tried to place a cookie.

Comment: I speak only of cookies that are set for my domain. I do not speak of foreign domains.